# Clarification on $L^1$ convergence

Tags: real-analysis

I am asked to prove the following:

Let $f_h(x)=f(x-h)$.

$(1)$ If $f$ is a continuous function of bounded support, then $\vert \vert f_h-f \vert \vert_{L^1} \rightarrow 0,$ as $h$ goes to $0$.

$(2)$ If $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, then $\vert \vert f_h-f \vert \vert_{L^1} \rightarrow 0,$ as $h$ goes to $0$.

Now I know how to do the first, but is there any work to do for the latter? since continuous function of bounded support are dense in $L^1$ is there much work for $(2)$ or? So can I approximate $f$ by a continuous function of bounded support for $(2)$?

Comment: Try writing down the estimates and see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is correct. We need the following observation: for any $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ we have that $\|f\|_1=\|f_h\|_1$ for all $h\in\mathbb{R}$. Prove this first for simple functions using the fact that the Lebesgue measure is invariant under translation; then prove this for positive, measurable functions by an approximation argument and finally prove this for $L^1$ functions by breaking them down to their real and imaginary parts first and then positive and negative parts too.

Now let $f\in L^1$ and $\varepsilon>0$. Find a function of bounded support so that $\|f-g\|_1<\varepsilon$. Then
$$\|f-f_h\|_1\leq\|f-g\|_1+\|g-g_h\|_1+\|g_h-f_h\|_1=\|f-g\|_1+\|g-g_h\|_1+\|(f-g)_h\|_1=$$ $$=2\|f-g\|_1+\|g-g_h\|_1<2\varepsilon+\|g-g_h\|_1\xrightarrow{h\to0}2\varepsilon.$$
Since $\varepsilon>0$ is arbitrarily small, this proves that $\|f-f_h\|_1\to0$.

Comment: and one last clarification, $\vert \vert f_h-f \vert \vert_1 \rightarrow 0$ is another way of saying $f_h-f \in L^1$ or simply $f_h-f$ converges IN $L^1$?

Comment: @HossienSahebjame Well, as I say in the first paragraph, $\|f_h\|=\|f\|$. So, if $f\in L^1$ we have that $\|f-f_h\|\leq\|f\|+\|f_h\|=2\|f\|<\infty$, so $f-f_h\in L^1$.